# Microsoft Advertising in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to use Microsoft Advertising SDK in Delphi application?
  e.g. to generate the necessary html tags in the visual studio?

Comment: Looks rather XAML/WPF centric to me

Comment: There is html5  stuff also ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-walkthroughs-html5(v=msads.10).aspx